# I replaced the cylinder on my Honeywell HM750 but the 'replace cylinder' light is still on

Tags: humidifier

This is regarding a Honeywell HM750 Humidifier, I installed a couple of years ago. I just replaced the cylinder for the first time.  Followed the instructions to the letter, and I checked the connections and cleaned the contacts.

The 'Cylinder' light is still illuminated.  It comes back on right after the self test.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Read the instructions. There is often a special step to reset indicators such as this. Sometimes holding down a button for 5-10 seconds.

Comment: Another thing to try is to unplug & wait a minute or so in case there's some RAM that need clearing.

Comment: This is sounding like Tegnigal Suppord.  "Reboot it again" :)

Comment: "To the letter" includes the indicator reset on page 25?

Comment: I know when I have received some rebuild kits the instructions that come with the kit do not have the reset. The op may not have had the complete manual reversed down vote as the question has information. But + jay got at least pointing the op to the location.